# How do you chain multiple observables?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

Let's say I want to show some user data which is on the server. I would search the server, cache it, and then present it to the user.
So my intial RxJava code would look something like this:

```
 ApiClient.getUser(userId), //An Observable that will spit out a UserResponse
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //for the API observable (Do i need this?)
    .flatMap(new Func1<UserResponse, Observable<DatabasePutResult>>() {
          @Override
           public Observable<DatabasePutResult> call(UserResponse response) {
                return Database.cacheUser(response);
             }
          })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //for the database observable
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(//handle DatabasePutResult object in onNext());
```

Now, I have two questions.

1. Is that the right way to chain the two Observables? If not, how should I be doing it?
2. If I wanted to handle the `onError` for the Api Observable, would I be able to that somehow while maintaining the chain? If not, what is the best way to do this? Do I really need to separate out the chain into two sets of RxJava calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need this:

`.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //for the API observable (Do i need this?)`

If you are interesting you may check current thread's id by this code:

`Thread.currentThread().getId();`

Everything else was fine.

2. You should look at this: [Error-Handling-Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators). In this case, I would advise to take a closer look at  `onErrorResumeNext( )`

Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: so if I understand this right, I should use `onErrorResumeNext()` if I want to try a similar but different observable (a different observable that emits the same output), but if i want to handle that observable's error I can do so in the `onError()` inside subscribe by checking `if(e instanceof SomeException)`

Comment: And what if you have two observables that emit the same Exception. Like for example what if I had a network call and based on that result, I do another network call. Both can emit HttpException. You can't really use `if(e instanceof SomeException)`. What would you suggest in that senario?

Comment: @Sree  

`ApiClient.getUser(userId)`  

It will emit only one `onNext` event or one `onError` event if i correctly understood your code snippet (you use Retrofit, right?).

Comment: yep, but I just used that as an example. What happens if I do `ApiClient.getUser(userid).flatmap(//some other api call)`

Comment: it all depends on the logic that you need, you can write like this
`ApiClient.getUser(userid).onErrorResumeNext(...).flatMap( v-> ApiClient.newCall(o.value).retry((count, throwable) -> throwable instanceof MyException || count < 10)).subscribe(...)` if you really need it:)